# C++ display array of bytes in hex

Tags: c++, string, dll, hex, hook

I've made a dll hook that will send address for Byte array that I need every time the event occurs on the main apps.

Display code :

```
void receivedPacket(char *packet){
    short header = packet[2];

    TCHAR str[255];

    _stprintf(str, _T("Header : %lX\n"), header);  // This works fine. It return 0x38 as it should.

    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), str, strlen(str), 0, 0);
    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), packet, 34, 0, 0);

}
```

this is the example of the byte array from that address, and this is how I want it to be displayed :
`05 01 38 00 60 00 9D 01 00 00 00 00 00 70 C9 7D 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 20 79 40 00 00 00 00`

But, with my current code, it will only display weird symbols. So how can we convert all those weird symbol to hex?

I'm actually new to the C++.

Comment: You have to **format** each byte.

Comment: loop? but, is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format each byte in the string:

```
static TCHAR const alphabet[] = _T("0123456789ABCDEF");

for (TCHAR * p = str; *p; ++p)
{
    TCHAR const s[2] = { alphabet[p / 16], alphabet[p % 16] };
    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), s, 2, 0, 0);
}
```